# Determine if a tablecell is really seen by user in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to find a way to check if several of my table cells are really being seen by users (let's say, if the cell is at least 1px shown, I consider it as being seen). And also need to make sure if users scroll up and down, I'll need to trigger the method. (This should be easy as I can put the check in listener method like DidScroll or something)

Seems like using `indexPathsForVisibleRows` can only give me rows that are almost 100% visible in the screen.

I'm searching for solutions, and looks like using `rectForRowAtIndexPath` and doing some math with `contentOffset` may give me what I want. Not sure if there's better way.

Anyone could help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Seems like using `indexPathsForVisibleRows` can only give me rows that are almost 100% visible in the screen."*

I'm not sure that's correct. Quick testing shows that even when just the first point of the cell is visible it's included.

However, you could accomplish this by implementing `willDisplay cell`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    bSeen[indexPath.row] = @YES;
}
```

Take a look at this example. Just put a `UITableViewController` into a navigation controller and assign its class as `SeenRowsTableViewController` :

```
@interface SeenRowsTableViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *bSeen;
    NSArray *colors;
    NSInteger nRows;
}

@end

@implementation SeenRowsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSAssert(self.navigationController, @"Example must be in a Navigation Controller");
    
    // series of row background colors
    //  to make it easy to see the last / next row
    colors = @[
        [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:0.75 blue:0.75 alpha:1.0],
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:1.00 blue:0.75 alpha:1.0],
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.75 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0],
        [UIColor cyanColor],
        [UIColor yellowColor],
        [UIColor magentaColor],
    ];
    
    nRows = 500;

    // add a right bar button
    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check It" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(checkIt)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btn];
    
    // init array with number of rows all set to FALSE
    bSeen = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        [bSeen addObject:@NO];
    }
    
    // use default basic cell
    [self.tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"c"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [bSeen count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    c.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    c.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count];
    return c;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    bSeen[indexPath.row] = @YES;
}
- (void)checkIt {
    NSUInteger idx = [bSeen indexOfObject:@NO];
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Seen: %ld", (long)idx];
}
@end
```

We use a series of colors for the cells to make it easy to see their frames. Each time we tap the "Check It" bar button, we change the navigation bar title to the index of the ***first row*** that has not been seen.

So, on launch (on an iPhone 8), we get this when we tap "Check It":

[image]

after slowly scrolling just a little, so the next cell is 1-pt visible, tapping "Check It" gives us this:

[image]

here's a zoomed-in image of the bottom:

[image]

As you can see, only the row separator and the first point of the next cell is visible, but our code has correctly flagged it as "seen".

Here's a Swift version, for anyone interested:

```
class SeenRowsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // series of row background colors
    //  to make it easy to see the last / next row
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 1.00, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.0),
        .cyan,
        .yellow,
        .magenta,
    ]
    
    let nRows = 500

    var bSeen: [Bool] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard navigationController != nil else {
            fatalError("Example must be in a Navigation Controller")
        }
        
        // add a right bar button
        let btn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Check It", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(checkIt))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn

        // init array with number of rows all set to FALSE
        bSeen = Array(repeating: false, count: nRows)
        
        // use default basic cell
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bSeen.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        c.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]
        return c
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        bSeen[indexPath.row] = true
    }
    @objc func checkIt() -> Void {
        if let idx = bSeen.firstIndex(of: false) {
            // set NavBar title to first row that has
            //  NOT been seen
            self.title = "Not Seen: \(idx)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much DonMag! willDisplayCell works for me. Looks like it works either scrolling up or down and yes, it'll be called when at lease 1 pixel is being rendered, which best fits my need :)